# Bitstamp streamline API: how to get all contents of the ordebooks?

Tags: api, bitstamp

I've been trying to work with Bitstamp streamline API, which uses Pusher.

So I managed to connect to some channels, specifically to 'orderbook' and it even returned me 6 items. However it looks like some kind of limit. Does anybody know how do I get the full contents of the orderbook (that is, all orders) throught this streamline API? (I know you can do it via regular REST api, but due to some limitation, I really have to use Websockets and Pusher in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet used Bitstamp's streaming API but I think it's fairly safe to assume that you will only get real-time changes via those pusher channels. That means you need to make at least one initial call to their official REST API to get the full orderbook, and then keep it updated by applying the changes that you receive from the streaming API.

If you are really stuck with websockets only (care to explain why?), you may need to build your own proxy middleware that can make that initial REST call and feed your client with the full orderbook via websockets.

Either way, be extra careful about relying on an unofficial and unsupported API which Bitstamp can change at any moment without prior warning.